# Assembly is not loading in main project when it is called from unit test project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I am facing an issue where unit test is failing.

I have kept all resources in resource dictionary in one assembly. I am referencing that assembly in one of my project. I am resolving that resources using pack. Now, I written unit test to my project.

When I run my tests. It is failing saying

```
        Test method AX.Sensis.PLog.PatientHistoryContainer.UnitTest.PatientHistoryViewModelTest.PatientHistoryEventTest threw exception:
     System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'AX.Sensis.PLog.PatientHistoryContainer.PatientHistoryViewModel' threw an exception. -
     --> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'AX.Sensis.Documentation.Resources, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencie
     s. The system cannot find the file specified.=== Pre-bind state information ===
     LOG: DisplayName = AX.Sensis.Documentation.Resources, Culture=neutral
      (Partial)
     WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
     WRN: Assembly Name: AX.Sensis.Documentation.Resources, Culture=neutral | Domain ID: 290
     WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
     WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
     WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
     WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
     WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
     LOG: Appbase = file:///U:/AX_Singapore_Sensis/Nebula/Tools/Build/TestResults/Deploy_IC018332 2016-07-13 12_43_19/Out
     LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
     Calling assembly : (Unknown).
     ===
     LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
     LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vs
     test.executionengine.x86.exe.Config
     LOG: Using host configuration file:
     LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
     LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
     Failed   PatientHistoryEventTest

     LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/AX_Singapore_Sensis/Nebula/Tools/Build/TestResults/Deploy_IC018332 2016-07-13 12_43_19/Out/AX.Sensis
     .Documentation.Resources.DLL.
     LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/AX_Singapore_Sensis/Nebula/Tools/Build/TestResults/Deploy_IC018332 2016-07-13 12_43_19/Out/AX.Sensis
     .Documentation.Resources/AX.Sensis.Documentation.Resources.DLL.
     LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/AX_Singapore_Sensis/Nebula/Tools/Build/TestResults/Deploy_IC018332 2016-07-13 12_43_19/Out/AX.Sensis
     .Documentation.Resources.EXE.
     LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///U:/AX_Singapore_Sensis/Nebula/Tools/Build/TestResults/Deploy_IC018332 2016-07-13 12_43_19/Out/AX.Sensis
     .Documentation.Resources/AX.Sensis.Documentation.Resources.EXE.

     Stack Trace:
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, St
     ackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
        at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, Stac
     kCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
        at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
     StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
        at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
        at System.Windows.Navigation.BaseUriHelper.GetLoadedAssembly(String assemblyName, String assemblyVersion, String assemblyKey)
        at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetResourceManagerWrapper(Uri uri, String& partName, Boolean& isContentFile)
        at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourceContainer.GetPartCore(Uri uri)
        at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPartHelper(Uri partUri)
        at System.IO.Packaging.Package.GetPart(Uri partUri)
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
        at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
        at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetContentType(WebResponse response)
        at MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponseStream(WebRequest request, ContentType& contentType)
        at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.set_Source(Uri value)
        at AX.Sensis.PLog.PatientHistoryContainer.PatientHistoryViewModel..cctor()
```

Comment: Have you added all the indirect references to the Test Project that might be required?

Comment: Update: I have found the solution.
When we run tests. Msbuild will copy the binaries to one location and it will execute the testcases. In my case it didn't copied one of dependent binary. so, I have used [DeploymentItem("RequiredDLL")].